# Confusion with asynchronous programming

Tags: asynchronous-programming

I have been reading about the concept but still it doesn't make sense to me. I want to clarify my question by giving an example.

First of all, if we have task1 and task2 which have to run in sequence, they call it synchronous. Whereas, if task2 runs before task1 finishes, it is called asynchronous. I came across such descriptions everywhere.

Where I am confused is that, if the tasks does not in order(one starts after the other finishes) how come things end up like we ordered them when we code line by line?

Imagine I write a code where task2 needs the final result of task1. In old way we would do it as:

```
var x = task1();

var y = task2(x);
```

So now above task2 needs x as an argument. But x can only return when the task1 finishes. Isn't it? So how come above task2 can start before task1 finishes? How can this work asynchronous way to make sense? Can someone clarify even though my definitions might not be correct?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean) might help.

Comment: My friend that's the surface knowledge with no example. I am confused at a very particular point.

Comment: @pnatk Linking to place where "*they* call it synchronous" may help others to reason about what you don't understand... Also consider specifying language/framework - precise meaning of "asynchronous" vary slightly between languages. (in this particular case the code shown is somewhat valid at least for JavaScript and C#). Also note that "synchronous" can mean two *very different* things in this context - "uninterrupted execution" and "execution in a sequence" - clarifying which meaning you use here would be nice too.

Answer (score 3):

Your particular example has a *data dependency*: Task2 is dependent on Task1 to finish.

You can still get the benefits of async, depending on your language/framework.

One particular way is that Task1 can return a `promise` (aka a `future`): A token that says "this is the answer of Task1, and you can have it when it is ready".  It just may not be ready *yet*.  So you can pass that *promise* to Task2, and *start* Task2, and eventually when Task2 gets around to needing the value from Task1 it can ask the promise/future for its value.  If Task1 is done: Then fine, Task2 gets the value right away.  Otherwise it has to wait for it.

Other frameworks/libraries/languages might not have promises/futures, but they'll have something *else*, e.g., *continuations* (which are just callbacks, really), or special keywords, or whatever, to make the dependencies work out.

"async" is designed to make the most of your processing power when there's a lot of *waiting* going on for other things to happen (frequently: The other stuff is happening somewhere out there in the network, e.g., a database somewhere).  It works without *you* having to write a lot of code to poll, or wait, or do threading stuff.  But it works *best* if you can arrange either *no* data dependencies or a *chain* of data dependent tasks.

Comment: What can task2 start to do when it only gets a promise but not the actual returned value of x? Lets for simplicity say task2 is taking the square of its argument. Since x is not ready what will task2 start doing? Could you give an example? Maybe I simplified it too much but that's my level.

Comment: Well, you can read up on promises, but the basic idea is you ask it for the value, and if it is not ready yet (because Task1 isn't done) then Task2 _waits_.  This is an automatic wait, arranged by the language/library/system.  If Task2 needs the value immediately then there isn't much overlap in computation that can happen - but that's ok.  Maybe you don't need the overlap.  You just want it to wait until some database access or remote network call is done, and continue when it has the result _without you having to do anything special to code that at all_!.

Comment: (In other words, your example where task2 just takes the square of its argument: it's not a good use case for async.  It's for when there's going to be waiting involved, and you don't want to write the code to do the waiting.  You want the _system_ to do the waiting and bookkeeping for you.)

Comment: Can you give an example which suits async case? A clear simple example.  I still dont understand.

Comment: Well I've mentioned database calls several times.  Those are slow.  So Task1 does some query against a database and returns a promise that says "Here are the rows that satisfy the query, you can have them later".  Your main task passes that to Task2 _and then the main task goes and does something else, whatever it was going to do!_.  Meanwhile Task2 asks for the value from the promise and _it waits_.  The main task is still going doing whatever.  Finally the database access is done, Task2 resumes, does its calculation, and sets _its own promise to the value_.  ... (cont'd)

Comment: ... Eventually the main task gets around to finally _needing_ the value from Task2 and asks its Task2' promise for it, gets it, and continues.  Note that _if_ the main task doesn't have a lot of other stuff to do then _there's less or no reason to use async_.  You use async if you've got stuff that takes time, you don't need it right away, and so you don't want to _wait_ for it.

Comment: But even stuff can take time task2 can depend on task1's result. In my example task1 might take 1 hour. But task2 needs x so async will never work?

Comment: I can't help you any further.  Unfortunately I can't express it any clearer than I have.  Maybe someone else will provide a different answer.

Comment: My example is very clear with two methods I need such example  code like couple of methods not paragraphs. When you mention all those database thing there's no picture appears in my mind about the mechanism. Thanks anyway..

Comment: @pnatk Don't confuse "asynchronous" with "parallel". Async doesn't mean there's some magic that happens that will allow task2 to do any work if it relies on the result of task1. Those tasks will still have to run one after the other. What it does say is that _the program that called task1 and task2_ is allowed to do other stuff while task2 is waiting for task1 to complete. It'll come back to task 2 and resume executing when task1 is done. In a non-async program, _the entire program_ will have to wait for task1 while task2 is waiting.

Comment: @pnatk In your example of task1 and task2, if there's nothing else for the program to do while task2 is waiting on task1, then there will be _no difference_ if those tasks are async or not. You will gain nothing.

Comment: @pnatk suppose you have to display a bunch of current stock prices.  You have to do an HTTP request for each.  Say each request takes a second.   For 10 stock prices thats 10 seconds if sequential.   If you start all of the requests at the same time it's much faster.

Comment: @EricKing - Good catch - I wonder if that is the OP's confusion: async vs parallel (concurrent)

Comment: I think by EricKing I am now exactly on the top of where my problem is. Let me explain. EricKing says that  "the program that called task1 and task2 is allowed to do other stuff while task2 is waiting for task1 to complete. It'll come back to task 2 and resume executing when task1" But now here is I can say the core of my confusion: If "the program"(I guess you mean thread?) goes away to another task to do something else while task2 is waiting task1, what is running task1 then? The program just turned its back to task1. Who is running task 1 at that duration? Exactly where I am confused..

Comment: @pnatk "what is running task 1 then" is not your problem. Could be that task 1 is running on another processor, or another core in the same processor (effectively the same thing), or all the tasks could be running on a single core processor. Task 1 itself might be waiting on some other task, like a network request. In any case, there will be a scheduler that lets each task/thread/process get some time, so even on a single core machine many things can be in process all at the same time. This answer is a good one because it points out the role of data dependencies in ordering those tasks.

Comment: if task1 is left alone by its thread what is running it?

Comment: Nothing is running it.  It's parked somewhere in some data structure that the language/library maintains.  Just like if you've got more processes "running" on your system than you have cores.  The operating system chooses one process to run on each core and the rest it parks somewhere in some data structure (a queue, or set of queues).  The OS maintains that.  The language system maintains it for your async stuff.  Your task2 isn't _running_ when it is _waiting_ for task1 to finish.  It is _waiting_ in a queue or data structure for the task1 to provide a _value_ (its answer) to the promise.

Comment: okay task2 waits task1 that is clear. lets focus on task1. so task1 is not running at all when task1's thread goes away and starts working on some other task call it task3. now stop the time look at the situation: task2 is waiting(not running), task1 is not running as well(as you say) but task3 is running(because thread went to work on that). does that mean the thread will be switching its working on between task1 and task3? does that mean it will run a bit task3 and come back to run a bit more more task1 so forth and on? sort of multiplexing?

Comment: I think, @pnatk, that some of your difficulty rests with not really having a knowledge of basic _concurrency_: multiple threads of execution - cooperative in this case - managed by part of the system (the OS, or languages).  Synchronization through mutexes, which _also enqueue waiting tasks so they don't use resources while they're waiting_.  Async is a _refinement_ of that, within a process, where a lot of the details are (thankfully!) left to the language to provide so it is _correct_ and _easy_.  Do a bit of reading on the earlier concept of concurrency w/mutexes and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It’s really very simple. If task 2 needs the result of task 1 then it needs to wait for task 1 to finish and therefore task 1 and task 2 are not asynchronous to each other.

But if there is a third task that is independent, that can run asynchronous and in parallel to the others.

Comment: Its not that simple. see my comments

Comment: @pnatk It's exactly that simple. A task that needs results that don't exist yet has to wait for them, but if it can do other work while it waits it can go ahead and do that, and that's where the performance boost that async programming offers comes from.

Comment: ", but if it can do other work while it waits " what do you mean by "it"? is task "it" or program thread? what is task in your terminology? is it the thread? which thread? super super confusing

Answer (score 0):

In the example given task2 has a dependency on the result from task1. In this case, task2 cannot start before the result from task1 is available. Because of this dependency, the two methods cannot be run **concurrently** (at the same time).